# Can I disable Ctrl+Click in Visual Studio's C# editor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, editor

When working in C++ in Visual Studio, Ctrl+clicking on a word in the text editor selects it. When working in C#, on the other hand, Ctrl+click also does a Go To Definition when possible.

Can I disable the Go To Definition functionality? I'd like Ctrl+click to always only ever select the word, and nothing else.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can easily disable, go to Tools->Options->Text Editor->General-> Enable mouse click to perform Go to Definition.

[image: where to disable]

Note yo can also change the modifier.

Comment: Thanks. This option appeared to be completely invisible to me. It took me a couple of goes to find even with screen grab and dialog box side by side.

Comment: I'll have to be honest, I searched for "go to definition" in Quick Launch (Ctrl+Q) top right :)

Comment: The most annoying feature in Visual Studio ever! :)

Answer (score 2):

Under the Text Editor options, uncheck this

> Enable mouse click to perform Go to Definition